# Auth0 is causing my expo managed workflow EAS build to fail and I'm not sure why

Tags: react-native, expo, auth0

When trying to build my app on expo it is failing here:

```
Task :expo-linear-gradient:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease
> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources
> Task :app:processReleaseMainManifest /home/expo/workingdir/build/HalfBaked1/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
Error:  Attribute data@host at AndroidManifest.xml requires a placeholder substitution but no value for \<auth0Domain\> is provided. /home/expo/workingdir/build/HalfBaked1/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
Error:  Attribute data@scheme at AndroidManifest.xml requires a placeholder substitution but no value for \<auth0Scheme\> is provided. See https://developer.android.com/r/studio-ui/build/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.
> Task :app:processReleaseMainManifest FAILED
> Task :expo-location:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/expo/workingdir/build/HalfBaked1/node_modules/expo-location/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/location/taskConsumers/GeofencingTaskConsumer.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
> Task :expo-permissions:compileReleaseKotlin \> Task :expo-notifications:compileReleaseKotlin w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/HalfBaked1/node_modules/expo-notifications/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/notifications/permissions/NotificationPermissionsModule.kt:39:
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```

I tried to build it using the EAS build for expo and I expected it to succeed.

I'm using the managed workflow.

I am not sure why this is happening but any information would be much appreciated.

This is my app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "HalfBaked1",
    "slug": "HalfBaked1",
    "owner": "jsummers1329",
    "scheme": "myapp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.jsummers1329.HalfBaked1",
      "infoPlist": {
        "CFBundleURLTypes": [
          {
            "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["myapp"]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.jsummers1329.HalfBaked1",
      "intentFilters": [
        {
          "action": "VIEW",
          "data": [
            {
              "scheme": "https",
              "host": "dev-wf6hagbsmen8xmma.us.auth0.com",
              "pathPrefix": "/android/com.jsummers1329.HalfBaked1/callback"
            }
          ],
          "category": ["BROWSABLE", "DEFAULT"]
        }
      ]
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "ddf6f986-e5ae-4f81-b552-a260844b2706"
      },
      "auth0Domain": "dev-wf6hagbsmen8xmma.us.auth0.com",
      "auth0Scheme": "myapp"
    }
  }
}
```